# unable to downgrade from angular 6 to angular 5

Tags: angular5, angular6

I created my project using angular 6 but due to some reasons i want to rollback to angular 5,I tried following commands but it is showing some errors.

node version-  10.4.1

npm version-6.1.0

```
npm ERR! code ETARGET
npm ERR! notarget No matching version found for @angular/cli@1.7.
npm ERR! notarget In most cases you or one of your dependencies are 
requesting
npm ERR! notarget a package version that doesn't exist.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\TEKIZMA USER\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-06- 
27T0
_21_53_446Z-debug.log
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try to follow this [Stack Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48291128/8685260)

According to my knowledge first, try to downgrade NPM then angular. 
And you might need to read [this](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli#updating-angular-cli) too.

Try possibly this way

```
npm install -g @angular/cli@YOUR_DESIRED_VERSION
```

Comment: you're welcome @NishthaJain if you feel the answer is helpful please upvote and accept it so it can help others.

Answer (score -1):

You do not need to reinstall global version of Angular CLI.

Instead, you can use [NPX](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npx) library like:

`npx -p @angular/cli@<version> new <app-name>`