# how can i downgrade angular 9 CLI to angular 7 CLI without causing a lot of breaking changes to the application?

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I started a project with angular 7 and i upgraded my C.L.I to angular 9 using npm install @angular/cli and @angular/core which updated my c.l.i to angular 9. This change has brought a lot on me. Every time i access the URL through its URL, the site is always distorted and i will have to click randomly on the site before it returns back to normal. How can i downgrade the application's C.L.I to 7 without causing breaking changes to all the compatible packages installed?

Comment: 7 > 9 is a big leap of faith. Lots of breaking changes in 8

Comment: so one possible remedy is to go through all painful breaking changes while downgrading all to v7 yeah?
how can i know the package exactly responsible for the distort on the application?

Comment: If you're using version control, I would revert back to a known commit that works. If that's not an option, you can just figure out which version of v7 you want to go to and either install each package 1 by 1 or just update the package.json manually. Here's a similar thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48290712/how-to-downgrade-angularcli-version

Comment: ... if I were you, i'd downgrade to 8 (the latest stable release) and just go through the updates (to fix breaking changes). If you look at their support matrix, you'll see angular v7 will lose it's support soon (with 9 coming out). I'm not sure what your expertise is with angular, but if you don't stay up to date with them it's easy to fall behind and end up in a situation like you're in. I would recommend upgrading to whatever the latest version is for minor/patches. Major versions, however, I would wait for at least a minor/patch to come out first. Point being: Sat up to date with angular